# backup network for file server and NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-attached-storage, file-server

I have a server, file server and a NAS Server. The storage on file server is created using ISCSI on NAS Server, and it's include with users' files (stored on NAS Server ISCSI).

The problem is, when i have a network problem where NAS server and file server disconnected, the ISCSI is gone, and it really take a long time for a user to login to server since users file is on ISCSI that shared via file server.

So, i want to create a backup for my network so when NAS and File Server disconnected, it still can connected via this backup network.

i'm using windows server 2008 R2 standard and eonNas. how can i make a backup for my network like this??

thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimal performance and reliability iSCSI storage is typically connected to hosts via a dedicated network (or, in some cases, multiple dedicated networks).Rather than a "backup network", I think you should be thinking about a dedicated storage network. Doing that could be as simple as dedicating a couple of inexpensive layer 2 switches to handling only iSCSI traffic (though I'd spend a little more and get managed switches).

Isolating the iSCSI traffic to a dedicated network allows for:

- Maintenance on the front-end network w/o causing hosts to lose their connection to storage
- Use of jumbo frames (which may not be practical to support on the front-end network)
- Enhanced information security (confidentiality, integrity, availability) because the iSCSI network is not directly accessible by any devices other than the hosts and storage
- Minimizing potential non-deterministic behavior as a result of high-traffic or protocol-induced delays that might be present on the front-end network (think broadcast storms, adjacency table flooding when a layer 2 device "goes crazy" or an attacker launches `ettercap`, spanning tree thrashing nightmares)

The fact that you're having situations where "where NAS server and file server disconnected" seems to suggest that you're having stability problems on your front-end network. Isolating the iSCSI traffic to a smaller, dedicated, more predictable network wouldn't cost a lot of money and you'd probably reap major stability rewards.